# Read structured file with doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, rhapsody

doxygen noob here, but I can't find answers anywhere.

**My goal** is to parse this file and extract (1) the *parameter name* found under Classes -> Attrs (in this case `calParameterName_1`), and (2) the *description* (in this case `Description of ParameterName_1.`). Also, I only want to do this for parameters found as Attrs -> Stereotypes -> _name = "Calibration" (there are other parameters defined as "RAM" which I want to exclude).

I am not able to modify the files to include commented code which can be read by doxygen. Instead, I'm looking for a way to read/parse this code directly and translate it to documentation. How do I accomplish this using doxygen?

My projects have .cls files built from rhapsody models, which contain "tuning parameters" (calibrations) in a common structured format, like this snippet below (note, I've taken out a lot of the attributes to shorten...)...

This file defines which parameters are RAM vs calibration type. The example above is a calibration (which you can see from the attribute definition).

I don't know how to *read* code into doxygen, only used it for reading the comments I put above my classes.

```
{ ISubsystem 
    - _name = "ParameterName_1";
    - Stereotypes = { IRPYRawContainer 
        - value = { IHandle 
            - _m2Class = "IStereotype";
            - _name = "SignalDefinition";
        }
    }
    - Classes = { IRPYRawContainer 
        - value = { IClass 
            - _name = "ParameterName_1";
            - _description = { IDescription 
                - _text = "Description of ParameterName_1.";
            }
        - Attrs = { IRPYRawContainer 
            - value = { IAttribute 
                - _name = "calParameterName_1";
                - Stereotypes = { IRPYRawContainer 
                    - value = { IHandle 
                        - _name = "Calibration";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Rhapsody is not a language doxygen supports, so you have to use a filter (see manual, configuration settings) to transfer the Rhapsody code to a language supported by doxygen. I assume it is a computer language or is it something else?

Comment: doxygen version 1.9.4. I'll have to research doxygen configurations, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've done a bit of research and a doxyfile seems to edit parameters which I can tweak in doxywizard. However, I don't see how this can be used to read/parse code? How to I extract pieces of my .cls file and generate them into my output documentation?

Comment: As written you should study the setting `INPUT_FILTER` and see how you can use this to convert your source into a form suitable for doxygen (when it is anyway possible). (Note current doxygen version is 1.9.7 but probably won't have an influence on your problem)